# Grid make a column span entire row with dynamic columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

What I want to achieve is make `.row` cell aways stay on the additional row, and span across the entire row no matter how many columns:

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319464/make-a-grid-column-span-the-entire-row) with the `grid-column: 1 / -1` trick, but it doesn't seem to work on grid with dynamic columns, any suggestions?

### Expected result

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 8px;
}

.container > * {
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.container .big {
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}

.container .row {
  grid-row: -1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid 1</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div>COL</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div class="row">ROW</div>
</div>

<h2>Grid 2</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div>COL</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div class="row">ROW</div>
</div>

<h2>Grid 3</h2>


<div class="container">
  <div class="big">BIG</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div class="row">ROW</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you have 4 divs before the full row? Because if you are always expecting to put them on the top row it's one implementation and if you want to have a limit of columns it's another.

Comment: All divs should be on the same row. But ultimately it should not matter since `.row` should always stay on the additional row at the bottom no matter how many rows and columns there are

Comment: Why are you using `grid-auto-flow: column`?

Comment: Umm, for dynamic column population?

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the "row"? Regardless, I don't believe this is possible without knowing how many columns there will be and you indicate that this is not known before render.

Comment: Interesting. the result of GRID 3 is different in FF than to Chrome.

Comment: As I suspected this is a duplicate. The last column (`-1`) only works in an **explicit** grid which you do not have here. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052336/make-a-grid-item-span-to-the-last-row-column-in-implicit-grid

Comment: I will postpone dupe-hammering this one for a while for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `display: grid;`, you should use `display:flex;`, if you do this then your problem will be solved. I have created an example check it out:

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 8px;
    }

    .container>* {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      padding: 8px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container .row {
      flex-basis: 100%;
    }

    .container>div {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>COL</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div class="row">ROW</div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="container">
  <div>COL</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div>COL</div>
  <div class="row">ROW</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I think had to use grid since that's how my layout is designed. I added another use case to simulate what I have. The `.row` just acts like as you delete them, the grids maintain its structure but just add an additional row after that structure.